# I got this error but no idea where is the problem "Cant find the variable SafeAreaProvider"?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Got this error when try running npm run android.
`Component Exception`
`Can't find variable SafeAreaProvider` in files ***App.js*** and ***navigation/index.js***.
I dont even have ***SafeAreaProvider*** included or used in the files. It looks strange to me, any ideas ?
***App.js***

```
import React from 'react';
import Providers from './navigation';

const App = () => {
  return (
 
  <Providers/>);
}

export default App;
```

***navigation/index.js***

```
import React from 'react';
import { AuthProvider } from './AuthProvider';
import Routes from './Routes';
const Providers = () => {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <Routes />
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}

export default Providers;
```

Comment: Are you using any third-party UI library?

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started React navigation requires react-native-safe-area-context . Maybe you forgot to install it, or installed an old version

Answer (score 0):

Apart from installing `npm install @react-navigation/native`, you will also need to install its dependencies, which you can do by running `npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view`.

Answer (score 0):

If we are supposed to implement the navigation in the react-native application we must have to install all the libraries described in the npm documentation.

So be sure that you have installed all the peer-dependencies and followed the documentation properly.

for the stack navigation implementation, we must have to install the following libraries as per the documentation.

- @react-navigation/native
- react-native-reanimated
- react-native-gesture-handler
- react-native-screens
- react-native-safe-area-context
- @react-native-community/masked-view
- @react-navigation/stack

for more information check out the official documentation to crash the issue.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started